# Twilio send sms from python errors

Tags: python, sms, twilio

I am trying to follow the tutorial in Twilio to send an SMS message from Python.  I have followed their code, but am getting this error:

```
[root@helios03 ~]# python sms.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sms.py", line 10, in <module>
    message = client.api.account.messages.create(to="+12316851234",
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/twilio/rest/__init__.py", line 138, in api
    from twilio.rest.api import Api
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/twilio/rest/api/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from twilio.rest.api.v2010 import V2010
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/twilio/rest/api/v2010/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from twilio.base.version import Version
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/twilio/base/version.py", line 4, in <module>
    from twilio.base import values
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/twilio/base/values.py", line 12
    return {k: v for k, v in iteritems(d) if v != unset}
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Thoughts?  I did a "pip install twilio" to install the helper..

Their example code is:

```
# /usr/bin/env python
# Download the twilio-python library from http://twilio.com/docs/libraries
from twilio.rest import Client

# Find these values at https://twilio.com/user/account
account_sid = "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
auth_token = "YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY"
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

message = client.api.account.messages.create(to="+12316851234",
                                             from_="+15555555555",
                                             body="Hello there!")
```

I have replaced the to/from numbers and account sid/token to match my info...

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code  necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PEP 274 -- Dict Comprehensions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) states: `All implementation details were resolved in the Python 2.7 and 3.0 time-frame.`

You are using **python2.6**.